# python pool.map takes hours to run without respond

Tags: python-2.7

I ran the following codes with jupyter notebook, using multiprocessing library's pool.map. However it took hours to run without any respond. Does anyone ever encountered the same problem？or know how to resolve it? Thanks!

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import math 
import numpy as np
def simulate_geometric_brownian_motion(p): 
    M, I = p 
    S0 = 100
    r = 0.05
    sigma = 0.2
    T = 1.0
    dt = T / M 
    paths = np.zeros((M+1, I)) 
    paths[0] = S0
    for t in range(1, M + 1):
        paths[t] = paths[t-1] * np.exp((r - 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * dt + sigma * math.sqrt(dt) * np.random.standard_normal(I))
    return paths

I = 10000
M = 50 
t = 20
from time import time
times = [] 
for w in range(1, 7):
    t0 = time() 
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=w) 
    result = pool.map(simulate_geometric_brownian_motion, t * [(M, I),])
    times.append(time() - t0)
```

Comment: How about debugging it to see where it takes so long?

Comment: thank u Tavo, I just choose to quit.